# Why are some function in python called as attributes and others not?

Tags: python

In Python everything is object, but some methods are not called as attributes, but you pass them the instance of object as parameter. For instance:

function `len()` expects object - `len(str)` seems logical, because it clearly shows that strings are immutable.

But why then `str.find()` is called as attribute of str?

I thought that it is because `len` excepts more then just one type of object, but this could be solved with polymorphism, right?

Is there any reason for some functions to be called as `func(obj)` and some as `obj.func()`?

Comment: What you're asking could be more clearly phrased as why sometimes these are functions [the `func(obj)` case] and sometimes they're methods [the `obj.func()` case].

Comment: That said, the basic answer to the overarching question comes down to "the language design evolved over time, but functions defined early on weren't replaced for compatibility reasons".